# Update hidden input element with weekday value from jQuery Datepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m just not familiar enough with jQuery to get this working. Using the jQuery Datepicker plugin, and with already some help, I have it working except for also updating the hidden input element with the selected week day value. Everything I’ve tried interferes with the function of the Datepicker plugin. Any help would be welcomed.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title> jquery date picker </title>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $("#Datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function pickdate() {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
    var selecteddate = $("#Datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
    $('#Datepickerday').html(days[selecteddate.getDay()]);

    // also needs to update hidden input 'weekday' with day of week

}
</script>

</head>
<body>

Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Datepicker" id="Datepicker" class="Datepicker" onchange="pickdate();">
<br><br>
Day:&nbsp;<span id="Datepickerday"></span>

<input type="hidden" name="weekday" id="weekday">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like Datepicker has properties that will do this for you, I havn't checked/tested if it works with a hidden. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field

Comment: @Tony Datepicker can put the entire date in a hidden input, but not just the day of week.

Comment: You can format it according to the documentation, could you not just set the format so it only returns the day of the week?

Comment: @Tony But that will affect the regular datepicker field, too. You can't have one format for the visible field and a different format for the hidden one.

Comment: Oh, I take that back. There's `altField` and `altFormat` options.

Comment: Also, just a suggestion, if you are displaying the day you do not need to also store it in a hidden input. If you need to get at the day again you can just pull it from your display #Datepickerday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val()` to fill in the hidden input.

```
function pickdate() {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
    var selecteddate = $("#Datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
    var weekday = days[selecteddate.getDay()];
    $('#Datepickerday').html(weekday);
    $('#weekday').val(weekday);

}
```

Or use datepicker's options:

```
$("#Datepicker").datepicker( {
    altField: 'weekday',
    altFormat: 'DD',
    onSelect: function(datestring, dp) {
        var selecteddate = dp('getDate');
        $("#Datepickerday").text($.datepicker.formatDate(selecteddate, 'DD'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys… that gets it done.. Guess I need to get better with JQuery given how much I seem to need it.. The '$('#weekday').val(weekday);' works for now but in the future using the 'altField' and 'altFormat' I think would be better.